# Specifying ConnectionProperties When Creating New Connection in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to create a connection using a boto3 python script.  It's a connection to a mysql database on an ec2 instance.  I'm using the script below.  I'm getting the error message below.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I've used similar scripts to create glue crawlers without issue.  I'm pretty much following the boto3 documentation except I added username and password in the ConnectionProperties.  I'm not sure if that's correct.  Can someone please let me know if I'm doing this right, or else what I need to fix in my code?

code:

```
# create new connection

response = client.create_connection(
    ConnectionInput={
        'Name': 'tst_scrpt',
        'ConnectionType': 'JDBC',


        'ConnectionProperties': {
            'string': 'jdbc:mysql://dataxxx:3306/disxxx',
            'username':'root',
            'password':'ip1k5PNCxxxxx'
        }
        ,
        'PhysicalConnectionRequirements': {
            'SubnetId': 'subnet-0436167b7cbxxxx',
            'SecurityGroupIdList': [
                'sg-02c3f45ce51exxxxx'
            ]

        }
    }
)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidInputException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6ac0bdcfa816> in <module>
     16             'SubnetId': 'subnet-0436167b7cbxxxx',
     17             'SecurityGroupIdList': [
---> 18                 'sg-02c3f45ce51exxxxx'
     19             ]
     20 #             ,

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    659             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    660             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 661             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    662         else:
    663             return parsed_response

InvalidInputException: An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateConnection operation: Validation for connection properties failed
```

Comment: What is the `'string'` connection property? It would be `host` or something but not `string` I think.

Comment: @Lamanus thanks yeah, it should be JDBC_CONNECTION_URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the ConnectionProperties wrong.  replace 'string' with 'JDBC_CONNECTION_URL'.  The correction is below.

```
'ConnectionProperties': {
            'JDBC_CONNECTION_URL': 'jdbc:mysql://dataxxx:3306/disxxx',
            'username':'root',
            'password':'ip1k5PNCxxxxx'
        }
```